# Inner Join & show data by id user API

Tags: php, api

How to display student value data?
so for access parents can only see value data from their children.
Please help

[scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjUAT.jpg)

for the header I have put it in the conn.php file

```
<?php
require_once "conn.php";
$query = "SELECT student, name, payment FROM payment INNER JOIN parent ON payment. student_id = student. student_id WHERE student. parent_id = id login parent" ;
$sql = mysqli_query ($link,$query);
$ray = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
  array_push($ray, array(
    "id" => $row['id'],
    "student_id" => $row['student_id'],
    "date" => $row['date'],
    "grade" => $row['grade']
  ));
}
echo json_encode($ray);
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

function.php

```
<?php
function escape($data){
    global $link;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $data);
}


function username_check($username){
    global $link;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM parent WHERE username='$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0 ) return true;
    else return false;
}


function email_check($email){
    global $link;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM parent WHERE email='$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0 ) return true;
    else return false;
}
?>
```

I'm confused because I just learned about this and the error results;D

Comment: whats this `WHERE student. parent_id = id login parent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need something like this

```
SELECT
  m.grade,
  m.subject,
  m.date,
  s.name
FROM mark m
  INNER JOIN student s ON m.student_id = s.id
  INNER JOIN parent p on s.parent_id = p.id
WHERE
  p.id = *parent id*
```